# Where is the configuration that instructs linux 14.04 to enter single user mode?

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04

I have an EC2 Instance of Ubuntu 14.04 Fails to restart after stop/restart.  It was upgraded from 13.x and apparently AWS has the web ui setup to send a 'reboot now' command which instructs 14.04 to enter into this modified boot.

I can dismount the drive, remount it to another instance and manually reset the single user flag if I could only figure out where that setting lives.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the shutdown command to drop it into the init level you want.  From the command line, issue "**shutdown -h now -i 1**".  Replace the "1" with whatever init level you'd like.  1 is single user mode, 6 is reboot, etc.

Or, you can create an /etc/inittab file with **id:S:initdefault:** in it and reboot.  Ubuntu uses Upstart, not sysinit, but it'll parse the file just the same (/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf tells it to look and see if one exists, just in case).

Comment: Thanks for the response option #2 looks like its headed in the right direction for this particular situation with AWS.  If I'm understanding this correctly though, wouldn't it be 'id:2:initdefault:' to get it out of single user mode and back to normal operation?

Comment: To get it back to normal boot you can always edit the file and just comment out that line before rebooting it again.

Answer (score -1):

After booting up the system, select the boot option you want in grub and press 'e'.  Then type "Single" and hit enter.

Point of interest, however: Ubuntu 14.04 is not Linux 14.04, it's Linux 3.13.0.

edit to respond to comment: alright, I thought your system wasn't booting at all, just type init 1 if you need to go from multiuser to single user mode.  The config file you're looking for is in /boot/grub/grub.cfg.

Comment: I don't have access to the bootloader, this is an AWS ec2 instance so I don't have direct console access.

Comment: btw... Ubuntu is based on Debian which is a community driven Linux distro.  The latest version is 14.04 (http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/).  Still looking for the location of the config file that controls the boot mode.

Comment: okay, see the edit.